# Uniqueness of indecomposable decomposition (Krull–Schmidt) for finitely generated modules over commutative Noetherian standard graded rings

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, graded-rings-modules

Let $R_0=\mathbb C$ and $R=\bigoplus_{i\geq 0} R_i$ be a commutative Noetherian graded ring such that the grading is standard, i.e., $R=R_0[R_1]$. Let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module. Evidently, $M$ admits a direct sum decomposition into finitely many indecomposable modules, but my question is: When is such an indecomposable decomposition unique?

The case when $M$ is graded seems to have been answered at [Krull-Schmidt Analogue for Complete / Graded Rings](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77021/krull-schmidt-analogue-for-complete-graded-rings)  , but I am interested in the case when $M$ may not be graded.

Comment: TeX note: `\oplus` is for a binary direct sum, like $R_0 \oplus R_1$.  For an $n$-ary direct sum, `\bigoplus` is more appropriate: compare $\bigoplus_{i \ge 0} R_i$ `\bigoplus_{i \ge 0} R_i` to $\oplus_{i \ge 0} R_i$ `\oplus_{i \ge 0} R_i`, and especially $\displaystyle\bigoplus_{i \ge 0} R_i$ `\displaystyle\bigoplus_{i \ge 0} R_i` to $\displaystyle\oplus_{i \ge 0} R_i$ `\displaystyle\oplus_{i \ge 0} R_i`.  I have edited accordingly.